# passing scope variable from directive link

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I made an angularjs directive as below:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.driective('myDirective', function(){
 return {
  templateUrl: 'directive.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        'dirObj': '=object'
      },
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.message = "View Message";

        element.bind('mouseenter', function(){
          scope.overState = true;
          console.log('enter');
        });

        element.bind('mouseleave', function(){
          scope.overState = false;
          console.log('leave');
        });

      }
};
});
```

and inside directive.html:

```
<h1>{{ message }}</h1>
<div ng-show="overState">This text doesn't appear!!!</div>
```

**Here is the live code on [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/LO3FPEjxXuihDKKFVrAe?p=preview)**

The problem is that the scope inside the element.bin doesn't set the value of the variable "overState" can someone please explain why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Is `driective` a typo in your question? And where did you add `myDirective` in your template?

Comment: I added my-directive in the index file under the module, what I'm asking about the scope, scope.message is displayed but scope.overState is empty always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$scope.$apply`:

```
scope.$apply(function() { 
    scope.overState = true;
});
```

Angular wraps most of its built-in directives automatically so it will update via the digest loop, but if you bind your own events (i.e. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`) you'll need to kick the digest loop off yourself.

[Updated Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/trm398NfHBz6gJc2HPxz?p=preview)

---

**Update based on the comments below**

You can also use the built-in angular directives `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` and then you won't need to worry about evaluating the angular expression yourself.

```
<div class="directive-area" 
     ng-mouseleave="overState = false" 
     ng-mouseenter="overState = true">
  <h1>{{ message }}</h1>
  <div ng-show="overState">Test Text</div>
</div>
```

[Built-in Directives Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1NIdBmenKEAC2UYoIopP?p=preview)

Comment: thanx that solved the issue, but I'm still not convinced of the solution, I think there is a better way to do it.

Comment: The other thing you can do is use `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` because they're built-in angular directives. They end up doing the same thing though. If you don't like either solution, good luck finding one! Here's the example of that: http://plnkr.co/edit/1NIdBmenKEAC2UYoIopP

Comment: Also I have multiple divs like this in different pages, at the first one it worked fine but when I moved to the second page and mouseover the div I got an error message: Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: It's probably better to use the built-in angular directives when possible, otherwise you'll need to be aware whether or not you're already in the middle of an `$eval` or another `$digest` loop.